# Analytic solution of the non-linear ODE: ${u}''+\frac{1}{x}{u}'=-\delta e^{u}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am trying to find the analytic solution of 
$${u}''+\frac{1}{x}{u}'=-\delta e^{u}$$
given the homogeneous mixed boundary conditions 
$${u'(0)}=0$$
$$u(1)=0$$

How would one attack such a problem? I have been given that the analytic solution is 
$$u=ln\left ( \frac{8a/\delta }{(ax^2+1)^2} \right )$$ 
where $a$ solves $8a=\delta (a+1)^2$.

I am guessing the only way to solve it analytically is to introduce $x=e^{-y}$, but I don't see how would this workout all the way. The equation cannot be reduced to a 1st-order by a change of variable, nor is separable.

Any ideas?